# Can you submit apps to apple without watchkit when your app used to have watchkit in it

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit

So the situation is we used to have Watchkit integrated into out APP, the watchkit 1 stuff has long sense performing correctly, so we want to upgrade to Watchkit 3.  However we are not ready to release the Watchkit 3 stuff, but we need to put out an update for the phone APP.  **Has anyone ever had a watchkit App/Extension in one version uploaded to the store, then in a later version removed the watchkit part?**  I've looked thru the apple guidelines, and there is nothing forbidding this, but they like to take "liberties" with their rules. Thanks for any help with this!

Note: most questions on SO are about removing Watchkit, but none (i found) mention submitting to the app store afterwards/before that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: What forum should a question like this be asked in then? @Droppy

Comment: I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From personal experience:
If you have removed the watchkit target completely and submit a new version of your application there should absolute be no problem. The watchkit extension / watchkit app just gets removed when a user updates your application to the latest version.

Comment: Yes this is true. I have tested it.